# Add a widget (button) to HTML5 canvas in GWT

Tags: html, gwt, html5-canvas, gwt2

In smartGWT it is possible to add another widget (seems to use an interface) to an HTML5-canvas, as you can see in [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/AddbuttonstoCanvasSmartGWT.htm).

Now I'm trying to figure out, if this is possible in (raw) GWT2.4 too. Has anybody of you a working example using GWT without any additional projects (like smartGWT, gwtExt, extGWT, ...)?

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but for other readers' sake: the Canvas in the linked example belongs to SmartGWT and got nothing to do with HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: @targumon: imho is this SmartGWT-Canvas based on a regular HTML5-Canvas and customized.

Comment: Erik, this is not a matter of opinion :-D
just inspect it in a modern browser - when you use **com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Canvas**, and this is the case in the java2s.com example you gave, the resulting DOM object is a DIV tag: e.g. <div id="isc_174" eventproxy="isc_Canvas_125" ... > ... </div>


only if you use **com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas.createIfSupported()**, you'll get a <canvas> tag (on a supported browser, of course).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 canvas is not in the scope of GWT yet, but maybe you can just build que equivalent elements in your dom with [GWT dom API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/package-summary.html) and draw in it throught [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html) calls

Comment: I don't agree. With GWT 2.2 google added experimental support for HTML5 canvas. With GWT 2.4 the canvas is officially supported by GWT (See: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5.html ). JSNI is perhaps a solution - do you have a working example? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erik, i noticed the recent release of [canvas](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html) in GWT 2.4

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/canvas/client/Canvas.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not put arbitrary widget in a canvas. What you can do is draw images. So I guess the smartGWT widgets you refere to are nothing else but images.

If you have a GWT image object, this is how you get it to be drawn in a canvas:

```
import com.google.gwt.canvas.client.Canvas;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.ImageElement;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Image;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;

public class ImageCanvasTest implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Image image = new Image(
            "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f6/Gwt-logo.png");

        Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
        canvas.getContext2d().drawImage(
        ImageElement.as(image.getElement()), 0, 0);

        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(canvas);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't agree - watch the example. You can register a MouseHandler at the widgets put on the canvas. How to draw an image within a canvas I'm used to and is not the answer.

Comment: Now I am not a SmartGWT expert, but looking at the Canvas code in the SmartGWT project, I don't think the SmartGWT Canvas (http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/trunk/main/src/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.java) has anything to do with an HMLT5 Canvas. The SmartGWT Canvas is just named Canvas...

Comment: Again I do not agree: The Canvas of SmartGWT is an inheritance of BaseWidget, which again is an inheritance of a normal GWT-Widget. The SmartGWT-Canvas includes a JSNI method called "create", which calles the normal JS create function of a HTML5-canvas. In addition: I think it is impossible to create own browser-widgets not based on any of the default widgets, the HTML-definition supports.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a CSS style for your buttons. A style like this:

```
button {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;  
}

button.zoomOut {
    top:200px;
    left:265px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

button.zoomIn {
    top:200px;
    left:400px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

With absolute position you're able to put them anywhere on the screen.

Cheers